# Javascript unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting an unexpected identifier error with this line of code: `var player[data[x].split("|",1)] = data[x].split("|")[1];`

The response data is in this format:

```
Mike Trout|0\nRyan Braun|0\n...
```

Here is the full JS function:

```
function updateChance(round, pickNumber)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {round: round, pickNumber: pickNumber},
            url: "./lib/updatechance.php",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                var data = response.split("\n");
                for (var x=0; data.length; x++)
                {
                    var player[data[x].split("|",1)] = data[x].split("|")[1];
                }

                for (var r = 1; r < $('#battersTable').rows.length; r++){
                    //do something with player

                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your loop `for (var x=0; data.length; x++)` is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look what you did here

```
.split("|",1)  //wrong
```

and

```
.split("|")[1]  //right
```

another issue, you have `var` with the bracket notation, not going to happen.

```
var player[data[x].split("|",1)]  <-- var, should not be there
```

And the for loop is missing a check so that is going to run infinite.

```
for (var x=0; data.length; x++)  <-- data.length what?
```

Why are you splitting twice? Twice the effort, do it once

```
for (var x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
    var info = data[x].split("|");
    player[info[0]] = info[1];
}
```

If `player` is not defined globally, you will need to define it before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, and sorry for all the errors. This answer sorted it all out!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access an object indexer in the same statement where you declare the variable. The `split` function also only takes a single argument and returns an indexable array. So this:

```
for (var x=0; data.length; x++) {
   var player[data[x].split("|",1)] = data[x].split("|")[1];
}
```

Should be:

```
var player = {};
for (var x=0; x < data.length; x++) {
   var value = data[x].split("|")[1];
   player[value] = value;
}
```

Also storing the result of the split operation in an intermediate variable, and fixing the loop syntax issues which would've caused the loop to crash at the end anyway, had the syntax error not prevented the code from running.

All in all, since you had quite a few syntax problems, I would recommend running your code through a linter such as [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/). It'll give you a detailed error report of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
var player[data[x].split("|",1)] = data[x].split("|")[1];
```

the keyword `var` doesn't make sense. You need it only to declare a local variable, what follows here is instead just an assignment.

There are other issues (see other answers and comments) but this is actually the syntax error that the borwser is reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to do this:

```
     var player = {};
     for (var x=0; data.length; x++) {
        var flds = data[x].split("|");
        player[flds[0]] = flds[1];
     }
```